# How can i store something in the application cache for an unlimited amount of time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

How can i store something in the application cache for an unlimited amount of time?

I have tried storing the data using HttpContext.Application["foo"] = bar. But this data gets cleared after a while.

Comment: It gets cleared when iis restart or recicle , u need to save to the DB or file so you can retrive it later

Answer (score 0):

You can add great expiration time for it in `web config` like this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires"
            httpExpires="Tue, 22 Aug 2037 12:00:00 GMT" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache) for more information.

Comment: @John Staurt Please upvote and accept this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.